# Нет доступа к папке Azure (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

У меня есть веб-приложение, которое записывает видеофайлы в папку внутри проекта

После этого он отображает видео для просмотра

С записью все в порядке.

Но когда я пытаюсь показать видео, я получаю эту ошибку

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Когда я запускаю веб-сайт на локальной машине, все в порядке, и видео отображается

Я сталкиваюсь с этой проблемой только на хостинге (Azure)

Вот код контроллера

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostRecordedAudioVideo()
{
    foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
        var file = Request.Files[upload];

        file?.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, Request.Form[0]));
    }
    return Json(Request.Form[0]);
}
```

Самое интересное в том , что я вижу файл в папке используя подключение через ftp

Скрин собственно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли вижу такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть предположение что трабл в доступах к папке

Но вопрос, как это  пофиксить?

Answer (score 0):

IIS не отдает статические файлы, для которых у него не прописан mime type. Т.е. он просто не знает, является ли ваш файл статическим и безопасно ли его отдавать первому встречному.

Пропишите в web.config на уровне сайта

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Но вообще идея заливать хоть что-то прямо в корень сайта - сомнительна. Лучше заливать в Azure Storage - и отдавать пользователю прямо оттуда.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую так. Потом припилю сторейж

Comment: Но есть вопрос. На локалке же он отдаёт

Comment: @Eugene на локалке в IIS он уже прописан по умолчанию конфиге IIS. Не знаю почему настройки по умолчанию разные в IIS и в App Services, просто сам недавно наступал на те же грабли, но с .woff

Comment: Спасибо, помогло